# Exporting Excel 3D Surface Data to Triads in ASCII text document

Tags: excel, ascii

Using Excel, I have made a 3D matrix with the following steps.

1. I put numbers in column A, rows 2-27.
2. I put numbers in Row 1, columns B-S
3. I set the value of element B2 with `=MIN($A2,ROUND(($A2*0.5)+($B1*0.4*RAND()),0))`
4. I then click in B2, hold the mouse down and drag down to S27 so that I now have a matrix whose values are a function of the values in column A and row 1.  This can be displayed as a function with the 3D surface plot.

My question is, is there a way to export this matrix to an `ASCII` file where each row is a triad consisting of the explanatory variables and the dependent variable?  For example
F1,A12,MIN($A2,ROUND(($A12*0.5)+($F1*0.4*RAND()),0))

I have tried exporting to a CSV file but it gives a matrix where I want a set of rXc triads where r is the number of rows an c the number of columns

Comment: Is this what you trying to achieve? [unpivot](http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)

Comment: @unpivot.  Sorry, I do not understand your comment.

Comment: I will try again: [Is it possible to “unpivot” or “reverse pivot” in Excel?](http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)

Comment: Sorry.  I thought unpivot was your screen name.  Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to achieve.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link for a similar problem:

[Is it possible to “unpivot” or “reverse pivot” in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel)

Also, as you are using `RAND()` the pivoted result will not have the latest update. Suggest to copy and paste as values before doing unpivot.